# Adress a member of Object inside such a member

Tags: java, object

I tried to simplify as much as possible to not spam you with a wall of code from my game

Say I have a Object of the class **XY** which holds a ArrayList of the Objects **Z**.
How can I address a member (**int number**) of the **XY** Object from a methode inside the class **Z**.

```
class XY {

   static int nextID = 0;

   final int id;

   int number;  

   List<Z> zList = new ArrayList<Z>();

   XY(int number) {
      this.id = nextID++;
      this.number = number;
      zList.add(new Z(id));
}
```

..

```
class Z {

   final int id;

   Z (int id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   void getXYNumber() {
      int n = // ?
   }

}
```

I could only find a workaround because in my case the class **XY** is also just stored as an Array in the class calling it now **ABC** and all **Z** objects have the same **id** as the class **XY** which holds the **Z** objects, so I can use this **id** to identify the object **XY** inside **ABC** from the methode **getXYid** inside **Z**, I'm calling.

```
class ABC {

   static XY[] = new XY[]{12, 45, 86};

   static XY getXY(int id) {
      for(XY xy: xyList) {
         if (xy.id = id) return xy;
      }
   }

}

class Z {

   void getXYid() {
      int n = ABC.getXY().number;
   }

}
```

Is there any keyword or something to get the specific **XY**, which hold the Z with the methode I'm calling, or this already the best solution?

Note: In this case the member to identify the class is the **int id** which could just be used as a index from the **XY** Array inside the ABC class, but in my case the object to identify the class is a enum called **Owner** that are all the same for all **Z** objects inside the **XY** object, so that wouldn't work out.

Comment: "the specific XY" - how is anything supposed to know which XY instance you want?  If you want a Z instance to be able to refer to a specific XY instance, you will need to give it a reference.  (For example, `class Z { private final XY xy; public X(XY xy) { this.xy = xy; } }`)

Comment: I want to know a way to get a reference inside a Z to the specific XY which holds the said Z.

Answer (score 1):

Create a field of type `XY` in `Z`, and set it's value when creating `Z`. It would also remove the need for copying the `id` field.

```
class XY {
   static int nextID = 0;

   int id;
   int number;  

   List<Z> zList = new ArrayList<Z>();

   XY(int number) {
      this.id = nextID++;
      this.number = number;
      zList.add(new Z(this));
}

class Z {
   XY xy;

   Z (XY xy) {
      this.xy = xy;
   }

   int getXYId() {
       return xy.id;
   }

   int getXYNumber() {
      return xy.number;
   }
}
```

This type of circular reference is generally considered bad practice and in many cases indicates that you need to review your application architecture/design.

Comment: could you elaborate the last sentence?

Comment: This [answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/12030) provides a good summary.

Comment: it provides nothing related

Comment: I think this statement is too broad.  In complex cases, it's not at all uncommon to need things pointing at each other; I'm a compiler maintainer and it's impossible to imagine the various entities representing, say, declarations, methods, enumeration objects, etc., not pointing at each other all over the place.  For simple apps you may be right.

Comment: @ajb That's why I said "in almost all cases". I know there are exceptions, and I have them in my own code, but I'm very aware of them and know the risks they create.

Comment: P.S. In the link you refer to, the questioner says it's *not* about cases like "pointer-to-parent" ... and this example looks a lot to me like a pointer-to-parent case.

Comment: @ajb It might qualify. The code is too much simplified to be able to pass a judgement. That's why I softened my statement by saying "generally" and "in almost all cases". I'll rephrase to: "many cases".

Comment: The thing is my case XY is a class called Player for a game, and the player has an array of Citys.

Now each round the city calculates some stuff like happiness and this is influenced by a luxury rate saved in the player class, so I need this value inside a calculate() methode in the City class.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are two simple solutions. If the value of `number` in `XY` does not change, I would suggest passing `number` to the constructor of `Z` like:

```
class Z {

   int xyNumber
   final int id;

   Z (int id, int xyNumber) {
      this.id = id;
      this.xyNumber = xyNumber;
   }

   void getXYNumber() {
      int i = // ?
   }

}
```

In the above example, you can call your constructor like: `new Z(id, number);`

If the value of number will change, you can pass the actual `XY` object to the constructor of `Z`. This object is a reference so if the original changes, the version inside the `Z` object also changes. This gives you the most current `number` value. When the `Z` object is passed to another `XY`, you can update the `currentXY` using the `void setXY(XY)`

```
class Z {

   final int id;
   XY currentXY;

   Z (int id, XY currentXY) {
      this.id = id;
      this.currentXY = currentXY;
   }

   void getXYNumber() {
      int i = // ?
   }

   void setXY(newXY) {
      currentXY = newXY;
   }

}
```

In the above example, you can call your constructor like: `new Z(id, this);`. they keyword `this` will give you the current object you are working with, which in your case is the `XY` object.

Comment: Doesn't this lead to something that Z contains XY and XY contains Z? Or is this totally fine because it's all just references to each other?

Comment: @Linard yes it leads tot that situation, however it is considered to be 'smelly code'. Personally I would prefer it over accessing it via ABC because you make Z dependent on ABC as well as XY.

Comment: In my special scenario the id was a enum, so to solve this, I put in the enum the reference of XY. And because every object Z has this enum as well I can simply call it over enum.xy.ect..